# Why don't most cars have a feature to keep the engine running with the doors locked?

Tags: locks

In the summer it's nice to keep the engine running while you step outside for a few minutes in order to keep the AC running at full speed. However most cars I've seen don't have this feature and you have to choose between keeping the doors locked and keeping the engine running, even with keyless models.

Why isn't there a feature to lock the doors while keeping the car on?

Comment: If you have two keys you can normally leave one key in and lock the door with the other using the actual physical lock (not the remote buttons)

Comment: My jaguar won't let you lock the car with one key when the other is in the ignition : not an opinion as I have tried it !!!

Answer (score 2):

I would think it would be because so many owners would be capable of locking their keys in the car...

Also, in some countries, it is an offence to leave a car running if no-one is in it.

Comment: But in order to lock the doors from the outside you need to have your keys?

Comment: No, some cars you can operate the lock with the door open and shut the door - ex-girlfriend did that to me - after being told "don't lock the door and shut it" ...